# 'Use of undeclared type' error when using user-defined variable

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have two classes (`ClassA` and `ClassB`) and a `ViewController`.

**ViewController:**

```
var cells: [ClassB] = []
height: CGFloat = something
instance: ClassA = ClassA()
cells.append(ClassB(height: height, data: instance))
```

**ClassA:**

```
class ClassA {
    var a: Int
    var b: String
    init (a: Int, b: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
    convenience init () {
        self.a = 10
        self.b = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

**ClassB:**

```
class ClassB {
        var c: String
        var data: ClassA   //use of undeclared type error here
        init(height: CGFloat, data: ClassA) {
            self.c = "\(height) is the height"
            self.data = data   //use of undeclared type error here
        }
    }
```

The project **builds without errors**, but when I run it, these two errors show up. Also, I noticed that variables of datatype `ClassA` are an `<<error type>>`.

*P.S. I'm using Xcode 7 Beta*

Comment: Try cleaning you build (Command-Shift-K) and trying again.

Comment: I did it, and it's still the same error. Builds successfully and when I run it, the error instantly pops up with a notification saying build failed.

Comment: Try clearing Xcode's Derived Data, the restarting Xcode.

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting a build error. When I command click on ClassA it doesn't open up the swift class file, it looks like it's not detecting it. Where as I've used it in other classes and the command click opens the swift class file. Also, on the line with the error, the color of the keyword 'ClassA' is blue like the pre-defined data types like 'Int', where as its green everywhere else.

Comment: I also noticed that variables of datatype ClassA are now <<error type>>, which explains why command click doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, that was a totally weird error. I literally made another swift class and copied over the same code and I had no error... Do you have an idea what might have caused that?

Comment: I've had this happen before…it's just a bug in the compiler. Sometimes it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have removed the "ClassA.swift" file from your target. You can check this under the file attributes inspector on the right. Look under "Target Membership" section - the checkbox next to your app target should be ticked, otherwise it won't be compiled when you build, and other classes in that target won't recognise it.